# Variable values in DbUnit's XML File

Tags: java, database, dbunit

I have two tables "Genre" and Libraire. Librairie has a foreign key that reference Genre on its ID field. This field is auto-genereted.

I'm performing tests with DbUnit. At the beginning of each test, I insert rows (with an XML file) first in Genre, then in Librairie. And that's where I have a problem : I have no idea to know in advance what will be the ID of the Genre I just generated, and I can't fill in the foreign key field on Librarie.

Is there a way to retrieve the ID of the Genre I just created and fill the foreign key field on Librairie, directly in the XML ?

Comment: Why don't you hard-code the IDs in your XML file? Which database are you using and how is the ID column defined?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the implementation of the database.

HSQLDB for example starts numbering IDs at 0 by default, but it would be more convenient to set the IDs in the XML file yourself, so you have complete control over the data at the beginning of your test.